# How to compute P-splines penalties with Harville's algorithm?

Tags: mixed-model, regularization, splines

I am trying to understand how to actually implement the Harville-Fellner-Schall algorithm for the estimation of the P-splines penalties presented in Appendix E (Sec. E.2) of Marx and Eilers [1]. Let me summarize here the main points. Given a P-spline basis matrix $B$, the data vector $y\in \mathcal{R}^m$ and the discrete derivative operator matrix $D$ of order $d$, the estimate $\hat{\alpha}$ of the spline coefficient vector is given by the solution of the linear least squares problem
$$
%\usepackage{physics}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argminB}{argmin}
\hat{\alpha} = \argminB_\alpha \left(\Vert y - B\alpha\Vert_2^2 + \lambda \Vert D \alpha\Vert_2^2\right),
$$
where $\lambda$ is the parameter that control how *wiggly* the smooth regression function will be. It is possible to reparameterize this problem in terms of the mixed model
$$
y = X\beta + Zc + e \quad {\rm with} \quad c=B\alpha \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\tau^2I) \quad {\rm and} \quad e \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 I).
$$
Expressions for $X$ and $Z$ are in [1, Appendix E]. It turns out that
$$
\lambda = \frac{\sigma^2}{\tau^2}.
$$
At this point Marx and Eilers propose an iterative algorithm that estimates alternatively $\{\hat{\beta}, \hat{c}\}$ and $\{\hat{\tau}^2, \hat{\sigma}^2\}$ until convergence. This algorithm is based on works by Harville, Fellner and Schall.
The estimating equations for the variances are
$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\trace}{trace}
\hat{\tau}^2 = \frac{\Vert \hat{c}\Vert_2^2}{d - \trace{(T)}}, \quad \quad \hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{\Vert \hat{y-X\beta -Z\hat{c}}\Vert_2^2}{m - \trace(T)},
$$
where
$$
S = R^{-1} - R^{-1}X(X^{\rm T}R^{-1}X)^{-1}X^{\rm T}R^{-1},
$$
and
$$
T = I - (I + Z^{\rm T}S Z G)^{-1}.
$$
The problems is that when I look at the implementation of this method in the sample code accompanying the book, I see, for example from [Harville_extended.R](https://psplines.bitbucket.io/Support/Harville_extended.R), something like

```
lambda = 1
BtB = t(B) %*% B
Bty = t(B) %*% y
n = ncol(B)
D = diff(diag(n), diff = d)
P = t(D) %*% D
for (it in 1:nit) {
    a = solve(BtB + lambda * P, Bty)
    G = solve(BtB + lambda * P, BtB)
    ed = sum(diag(G))
    yhat = B %*% a
    sig2 = sum((y - yhat) ^ 2) / (m - ed)
    tau2 = sum((D %*% a) ^2) / (ed - d)
    lambda = sig2 / tau2
}
```

It is easy to see in the code above that `sum(diag(G))` is the trace of the *hat* matrix
$$
H = B(B^{\rm T}B + \lambda D^{\rm T}D)^{-1}B^{\rm T}
$$
however I do not see an immediate relation between H and the
matrix T defined above. Any ideas?

[1] Eilers and Marx. Practical smoothing: The joys of P-splines. Cambridge University Press, 2021.